# Typing issue in HUE

Tags: cloudera, hue

If I am typing one letter in HUE IDE in hive notebook, multiple characters are getting typed automatically. As the screenshot is given below. Could you please help me on this.

[image]

Comment: Are you using a tool like AimKeys that allows you to define keyboars shortcuts for single characters? Does this happen only with certain characters? Are the appearing characters always the same? Do other people have the same problem from your machine? Do other people have the same problem from their machine? Have you tried restarting HUE?

Comment: This happened a (very) long time ago. Which Hue version are you using? (latest is 4.4 and soon 4.5)